# How to set screen/window size when using GhostDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am using the GhostDriver as the WebDriver implementation in a Java-based project. I want to take snapshots of the pages. The default page size is kind of awkward, so I want to control the page size of the snapshots. However, I can't find any examples from Google. So, can someone tell me how? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried `setSize()` method from `WebDriver.Window`? [Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java) is the documentation.

```java
// untested Java code, only provides the logic
// please debug and refer to the documentation

import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;

WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
// or driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743350/how-to-set-screen-window-size-when-using-ghostdriver");
```

Comment: It works! Many thanks. :-) BTW, just to make it clearer, Dimension = org.openqa.selenium.Dimension as in `new Dimension(1920, 1080)`

Comment: It is not working for me. Could you please let me know is there any other option