# Unable to Maximize the Browser in Selenium When I run Selenium Scripts in background

Tags: java, selenium, browser, selenium-chromedriver, background-process

Maximize code of selenium is not working when I run the script in Background. The Maximum size of the window will be 1036, 780. How browser window can be maximized in Background?

Comment: Are you referring to the GhostDriver?
This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743350/how-to-set-screen-window-size-when-using-ghostdriver

Comment: I am not running as headless, I am running as a Background process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Run Selenium Tests many times in the background I found that browsers will have given max and min sizes. 
 - Max Size in Background (1036, 780) 
 - Min Size in Background (415, 125)